# SEO: <itemprop> not working

Tags: seo

I have correctly inserted all required  snippets needed in order to have star ratings and other info show up on google results.  After double checking the Google Structured Data Testing Tool to make sure Google could properly sequence and extract itemprop data from my site, I am still seeing google results without ratings. Any ideas?

Comment: Just because you use the markup doesn't mean Google will show that in their results.

Comment: I'm in doubt whether this question should belong on Stackoverflow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanded data is shown only if your search result is deemed to be relevant. Note that Google spiders will take some time to reindex your web site. Check in a week or two. You can use the Webmaster Tools to have some feedback about indexing.